# Tagging and adding attributes on OSM road layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, grass-gis, route

I have downloaded an OSM road layer and I want to add attributes and tag specific line segments. I have another layer of centroids from a polygon layer of cities which will be the basis for my nodes. How can I tag/ select specific line segments based on the nodes layer (route from point A to point B) and is it possible to do this in batch processing? I want to add attributes (i.e. funding agency) to these specific segments. Do you know a tool/ plug-in in QGIS or GRASS that can do this?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly, QGIS can not edit an .osm-file.

Therefore you can make use of JOSM: https://josm.openstreetmap.de/

If you save those .osm-layers as a different layertype (eg. shapefile, geopackage, ...) you can edit them and add the desired tags

Answer (score 0):

Use the routing tool from the OSM Tools plugin to create the routes as a separate line layer.

Then use `Spatial Query` (in old versions of QGIS) or `Select by location` (in newer versions) to select roads that intersect the routes.

Once selected, you can save these roads as their own layer, or simply edit their attributes using the Field Calculator with the "update selected" option.

Note: As PieterB mentioned, the roads layer must be in a file format QGIS can edit.